# How to convert tuple query from "or" to "and" operation in php codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql, tuples

```
SELECT 
 `reference_of_common` 
FROM `tbl_taxonomic_character` 
WHERE
(root_character,character_sub1) IN (
                                  ('habit','Climber'),
                                  ('floral type','pentamerous')
                                 )
group by reference_of_common;
```

This query work as an OR operation. How can I write the query for AND operation?

Please help me

Comment: You could split your `IN` in two :  `(row_character, character_sub1) = ('habit', 'Climber') and (row_character, character_sub1) = ('floral type', 'pentamerous')`. But I guess you won't get any result. Could you show sample data and desired result ?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: i am desired for "reference_of_common" fields only where "root_character" and "character_sub1" is column(s) name. Example data are: ''root_character''=habit,leaf arrangement,bole and character_sub1=Climber,alternate,unbranched respectively

Comment: I can not convert the query to and operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT 
 `reference_of_common` 
FROM `tbl_taxonomic_character` 
WHERE
(root_character,character_sub1)IN(
                                  ('habit','Climber'),
                                  ('floral type','pentamerous')
                                 )
group by reference_of_common having COUNT(DISTINCT root_character)>1 ;
```